# Expect scripting TCL

Tags: command, tcl, delay, output, expect

I want to automate the following interaction using Tcl/expect, the script start and do nothing 
the expect command can not expect all the output of a command

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 10
set user username1
set password password@123

spawn  ssh $user@10.100.55.33
expect "Password:"
send "$password\r"
expect eof
send "cv mk ghassan-test-5\r"
sleep 45
expect "ok" { send "cv set ghassan-test-5\r" }
sleep 20
expect -gl "Ok" { send "cv rbset ghassan-test-5\r" }
expect eof
sleep 20
expect -gl "Ok" { send "cv ls\r" }
sleep 10
expect eof
send "exit\r
```

---

the `send "cv mk ghassan-test-5\r"` command runs with output as below

```
$ cv mk ghassan-test-4
Please wait while database is writing to disk.
Writing the database file can take minutes...
ok
```

the next command didnot run and didnot expect the "`ok`"

```
expect "ok" { send "cv set ghassan-test-5\r" }
```

but if i expect `minutes` it runs

```
expect "minutes" { send "cv set ghassan-test-5\r" }
```

the "`ok`" output takes one min to show

please any one have the same problem please help me

Comment: Maybe you should increase the timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expect "somepattern" {somecommands} "anotherpattern" {othercommands}` will only run one of the scripts if you receive the corresponding pattern before a timeout. If a timeout occurs and you have no script for it, nothing will be executed. Set `timeout` to -1 to wait indefinitely, or do something like this:

```
set timeout 300
...
expect {
  "ok" {
    send "cv set ghassan-test-5\r"
  }
  timeout {
    error "This is taking too long!"
  }
}
```

None of those solutions will handle an unexpected EOF. You should probably add a pattern script for that too. http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html

PS: I think that your sleep commands are unneccessary, and your `expect eof` commands too (they're probably just timing out).